# A vector space $V$ such that $V\otimes V \not \cong B(V^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $V$ be a vector space (not necessarily finite-dimensional) over a field $\mathbb F$. Let $B(V^*)$ denote the vector space of all bilinear forms  $V^*\times V^* \rightarrow \mathbb F$. It is "well-known" that the linear map $\phi: V\otimes V \rightarrow B(V^*)$ such that $$\phi(v \otimes w)(f,g) = f(v)g(w)$$ for all $v,w\in V$ and $f,g\in V^*$ establishes an isomorphism $V\otimes V \cong B(V^*)$ when $V$ is finite-dimensional. **I want to prove that this hyphotesis cannot be dropped**, that is, I'm looking forward a vector space $V$ of infinite dimension such that $V\otimes V \not \cong B(V^*).$

I am not familiar at all with infinite-dimensional vector spaces, besides the classical ones $\mathbb F[x]$ and $\mathscr C([0,1],\mathbb R)$, for instance. Which vector space should I look for? Is this problem more related to the cardinality of basis, in the sense that $\dim B(V^*)$ is also uncountable if $\dim V^*$ is uncountable? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If $V$ is countably infinite dimensional, then $V \otimes V$ is also countably infinite dimensional, but $V^*$ is already uncountably infinite dimensional. In general, when you have an infinite-dimensional space, taking an associated space of functions (the dual, or bilinear forms) will be far far larger than the original space.

Comment: $V^*=k^\omega$ the space of all $k$-valued sequences and $V$ the subspace of those vanishing for $n$ large enough.